# cakephp 2.x include userExists in validating login

Tags: validation, cakephp, authentication, validationrules, validationerror

I'm new to CakePhp, I'm using CakePhp 2.x. 
I am probably going about solving the problem below the wrong way. And I just know I'm overlooked something real simple but,.....

I'm validating login details based on 'Between 5 to 15 characters' they are retuning errors as expected.

```
[The MODEL]

public $validate = array(
   'username' => array(            
        'between' => array(
            'rule'    => array('between', 5, 15),
            'message' => 'Between 5 to 15 characters'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule'    => array('minLength', '8'),
        'message' => 'Minimum 8 characters long'
    )

);



[The CONTROLLER]

public function login() {

            if ($this->request->data) {

                $this->User->set($this->request->data);

                if ($this->User->validates() && $this->Auth->login()) {

                    if ($user = $this->Auth->user()) {                       

                         $this->render($this->Auth->redirect());

                    }else{
                        //??
                    }
                }else{
                        $this->User->create();

                    pr($this->User->invalidFields());

                        $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;

                        $data = compact('errors');

                        $this->set('errors', $data);
                        $this->set('_serialize', array('errors'));

                        $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');                                    
                }
            }


    }
```

So, the problem is, if the fields follow the rules in the model above even if the login details (the user) doesn't exist, no errors will be returned (no good). Would it be correct to add an other validation for this, adding another rule to check if that user actually exists? If so how!?

Or, do I work this into the controllers login function checking if the user exists? I'm a little confused now. Maybe I've been looking at the screen for too long.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are confusing registration (adding a user) with login (user already exists). The latter never has any validation whatsoever. All the validation including "exists" need to be done when the record is created, not when its too late and you are already trying to log this user in based on the valid (and already stored) data he is providing.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be correct to add an other validation for this, adding
>   another rule to check if that user actually exists? If so how!?

You can add as many rules as you want. In this case you want the rule "unique". [Read this section of the book about data validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html).

> Or, do I work this into the controllers login function checking if the
>   user exists?

**All** data manipulation and validation should happen in the *model* layer of the MVC stack. So put everything into a model method and pass the post data to it and validate it there. You can put all logic into the controller to but that's stupid in terms of not following the MVC pattern. Models can be shared between shells and controllers for example, a controller not. Again you could instantiate a controller in a shell but doing all of this negates any benefit and idea the MVC pattern has. Also a model is competitively easy to test. And yes, you should unit test your code. [Check how our users plugin is doing it](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Model/User.php#L593) for example.

Comment: I think I need someone to show me how to add a new rule in the Model $validation array which checks if the user exists. I want to be able to feedback to the user an error message saying something like "User unknown".

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple rules per field...

Follow this link to learn more about it...

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#multiple-rules-per-field

a sample code is given below

```
<?php

[IN The MODEL]

//the following code checks if the username is notempty, is a valid email and is it already taken or not...
public $validate = array(

    'username' => array(

        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email.',
        ),

        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email.',
        ),

        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'
        )
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: You say "checks if the username is not empty / is valid email and is already taken or not"

But, and this is the issue for me. What happens if someone logs-in and mistypes either their username/password (so validation is effectively ok, i.e not empty and follows the rules of char type/len). How do I give the user a message saying something like, "Username/Password unknown or incorrect" ?

I looked at adding a function into the Model which gets triggered in $validate, to check if the user does exists. This is to be if all the other validations pass, but I'm still looking how to do this  HELP!

Comment: @user1192941 : that part you have to do it in the controller...see this basic example ...watch the login function sample there..It would give you the idea....http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout